# Why does my jQuery .ready() function not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have recently updated my Wordpress blog which appears to have broken all my jQuery on the page.

I include a core.js file which contains a .ready method that modifies page behaviour, however since the update its stopped working. I believe its because Wordpress injects its own version of the jQuery library which is somehow conflicting with my script.

[Webpage](http://www.desidrop.com/)

[Core.js file](http://www.desidrop.com/js/core.js)
*Snippet of file*

```
    console.log('loaded core.js');
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    console.log('inside ready function');
    // other stuff goes on here
    }
```

The 'loaded core.js' debug line will fire, however the second debug line will not.
I'm not sure how to resolve, will greatly appreciate advise.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because all of the relevant code is in a link which is already invalid, because the problem has been resolved (incorrectly, I might add)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deregister the default jquery library. 
For more information, check [Function Reference/wp deregister script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script).

```
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
```

If you are going to deregister jquery, here's a way of removing it and adding a different version:

```
function my_jquery_lib() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   $lib_url = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"; // the library URL.
   wp_register_script('new-jquery', $lib_url, false, null);
   wp_enqueue_script('new-jquery');
}
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_lib");
```

Your website has an error in the console.

```
TypeError: f.browser is undefined
```

This maybe be causing the issue.

Comment: Why not teach how to use the included, correct, WP core jQuery, instead of instructing to deregister the core default library?

Comment: I agreed, I just thought about it. My post was just to answer this question to fix the issue, but I agree with you. I just added it.